# How to use hierarchical group in apache usergrid?

Tags: apigee, usergrid, apigee-baas

According to usergrid documentation -

> Groups are hierarchical. Every member of the group /groups/california/san-francisco is also a member of the group /groups/california
>   (https://usergrid.apache.org/docs/user-management/group.html)

Based on above concept I have created two groups - 
Group1 /california/san-francisco has users - user1, user2
and Group2 /california has users - user3, user4.

Based on usergrid documentation I am expecting that user1 and user2 should also be members of Group2 but they are not(if I am hitting url - /groups/california/users, it only returns user3 and user4, Should not it also return user1 and user2?)

Also I have posted an activity in Group2 /california which is appearing in feeds of users of Group2 i.e. - user3, user4, but not appearing in the feed of Group /groups/california/san-francisco users i.e. - user1, user2.

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest.